# Exclude META-INF/maven folder from the generated jar file

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to create a jar file which has all the necessary classes extracted within the jar. But for few dependent jar like [log4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17), it creates some folders inside `META-INF/maven/*`. I have a limitation that the server in which I will be placing the generated jar file will not have Internet connectivity. So if there is any content in this `META-INF/maven/*` folder then it gives me an error.

My maven descriptor looks like the following

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                <finalName>myclient</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am able to extract the required class files in the generated jar but the maven folder is still getting generated under `META-INF`. I have to manually delete the folder to make everything work. Please advice on how to automate this removal of maven folder from the generated jar file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [filters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#filters) inside the `maven-shade-plugin` configuration to exclude everything that is under `META-INF/maven` for every artifact:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

A solution for the `maven-jar-plugin` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960549/3764804).

Comment: Awesome Love you mate :)

Comment: Hi, I want to just removed the NOTICE and LICENSE files from the META_INF folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

Simple add this to either it is a jar,war,ear plugin

```
<configuration>
   ....
  <archive>
    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
   </archive>
   ....
</configuration>
```