# Maven: Exclude "META-INF/maven" folder from JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

I use [`Maven`](https://maven.apache.org/) to build a `JAR`. When I check the `JAR`, I see a `maven` folder inside the `META-INF` folder. I want it to be excluded from the build. My current build code in the `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>Libraries</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!-- <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                </excludes> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ...more plugins... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I read that using the `exclude` tags allows you to exclude something but it doesn't work. Maybe this only refers to local files/folders? The `maven` folder is not part of the source, it's just added by `Maven`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888257/3764804) answer kind of works but uses a different artifact hence a 2nd `JAR` is generated when I paste it into my `pom.xml`. I want to use my current build code and exclude the `maven` folder like described above. How can it be done using `maven` build rules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `maven-jar-plugin` uses the `maven-archiver` to handle packaging. It provides the configuration `addMavenDescriptor`, which is `true` by default. Setting it to `false` should remove the `META-INF/maven` directory.

```
...
<archive>
   <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
   ....
</archive>
```

You can find the reference [here](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/).

Comment: Does not work for me. All was built from clean, but it is still there. `<exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven shade plugin to create the jar and exclude the maven folder using following configurations in you pom.xml file:

```
<profile>
    <id>shade</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </executions>
                ...
</profile>
```