# Maven Eclipse Plugin automatically creates maven folder under META-INF

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have a `Dynamic Web Project` that we need to convert to `Maven Project`.
I am using `Eclipse 2021-03` with `Maven Integration for Eclipse v1.17.2`

I used a "normal" procedure to convert the project:

1. Right click on the project
2. Selected Configure -> Convert to Maven Project
3. Filled all the needed fields in the new pom.xml
4. Created source folders for maven (`src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/main/webapp`)
5. Moved all the files in the correct folder
6. Added all the needed Maven dependencies
7. Checked if in the Deployment Assembly all the source folders were deployed in the correct path
8. Finally, in the Build Path changed the Default Output Folder to `/target/classes`

Once finished, Maven plugin creates automatically a folder under `src/main/webapp/META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/`
inside this folder there are two files, specifically `pom.properties` and `pom.xml`

If I try to delete them, Maven plugin recreates them, same story if I try to delete the entire folder structure from `/maven`.

This is a screenshot of the folder structure, with the "unwanted" folders and files highlighted.

[image]

And this is my `pom.xml`:

[image]

Is it correct this behaviour?
Why are those folders and files created and why can't I make my Eclipse stop to generate them?

Any help would be highly apreciated!

Comment: Does the following work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960549/6505250

Comment: @howlger it is a different situation because I did not even try to create my war. The `addMavenDescriptor` is used to exlude those files from the final jar/war. My problem shows up at earlier stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved it by checking the following option under Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Java EE Integration

[image: Maven build folder solution]